# java.io.FileNotFoundException when uploading a file from a JSP

Tags: java, ajax, file, upload

I have coded a AJAX file upload feature in my application. It works perfectly when running it from my laptop. When I try the exact same file using the same app, but deployed on a jBoss server, I get the following exception:

```
2013-02-18 11:30:02,796 ERROR [STDERR] java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\TestFile.pdf (The system cannot find the file specified).
```

getFileData method:

```
private byte[] getFileData(File file) {

    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
    byte[] bytFileData = null;

    try {
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (fileInputStream != null) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] bytBuffer = new byte[1024];

        try {
            for (int readNum; (readNum = fileInputStream.read(bytBuffer)) != -1;) {
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(bytBuffer, 0, readNum);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        bytFileData = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    }

    return bytFileData;
}
```

Getting the file content in a variable (from the method above):

```
byte[] bytFileData = this.getFileData(file);
```

Making the file:

```
private boolean makeFile(File folderToMake, File fileToMake, byte[] bytFileData) {

    Boolean booSuccess = false;
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;

    try {

        if (!folderToMake.exists()) {
            folderToMake.mkdirs();
        }

        if (!fileToMake.exists()) {

            if (fileToMake.createNewFile() == true) {

                booSuccess = true;

                fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileToMake);

                fileOutputStream.write(bytFileData);
                fileOutputStream.flush();
                fileOutputStream.close();
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        booSuccess = false;
    }

    return booSuccess;
}
```

Any idea?

Thank you

Charles

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're just passing the file path as part of the request to the server, not actually uploading the file, then attempting to use that file path to access the file.

That will work on your laptop because the code, when running locally, has access to *your* file system and will be able to locate the file. It won't work deployed on a server because it's an entirely separate machine, and as a result won't have access to your file system.

You'll need to modify your client-side (AJAX) code to actually upload the file, then modify your server-side code to use that uploaded file. Note that AJAX file uploads aren't generally possible - there are plugins for frameworks such as jQuery that provide this functionality using workarounds.

I'm not 100%, but I think proper AJAX file uploads may be possible using HTML5 features, but browser support for that is likely going to be pretty poor right now.